# ASP.NET redirects to cookieless URL and loops on form login even though cookieless is set to false

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I have a very strange behaviour on my production server that only happens a few times during a week. On a form login POST a redirect is sent to what looks like a cookieless URL like:

"/(F(kD5qGnK-0b5L80VYgScenFuCnjQsLR67HhXq-BWXS1hL45hhqL8AiLlEyB-9CuJgutiyXzN42w8Bo_cm2o73GFWP_fuQ1AtPfXSaB7odZYAOBnuNW3Yy873fQDpRzYgOVo3Ee48gaCbS7FUIyOBA3CksCTZ3N6YCZ7pcZylZEo01))/SiteSpecificPath/CMS/edit/"

What normally happens is a redirect to just "/SiteSpecificPath/CMS/edit/".

This in turn leads to a redirect loop going back to the login.aspx page and continuing like that.

I don't want to use cookieless so the question is how this is triggered? And is there a way to disable this behaviour? I have looked through all levels of config files and cookieless is set to false on all places.

The site is an EPiServer CMS site, but in this case it seems to be related to a normal asp.net forms login procedure that for some reason triggers a switch to cookieless URLs.

I have found some references about cookieless triggering a redirect loop, but in my case the strange thing is why it even starts using cookieless URLs in the first place.

I have also done debugging using advanced logging to see all headers sent from the browser, but I don't see anything strange there. Cookies are sent as normal, including the ASP.NET session cookie.

EDIT: This is not an access problem. A given user can normally login, but sometimes this redirect loop is entered.

Some details: IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2, EPiServer 6 R2, ASP.NET 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the user doesn't has access to the redirect URL and this is why it redirects everytime to login page and continues like that.

Firstly check  if the user is authorized to access the page in the redirect url.If the user isn't authorized, redirect to a page that the user can access Or update the access rights for the user.

```
I don't want to use cookieless so the question is how this is triggered
```

When using FormsAuthentication, Check your Settings for same in web.config. As seen below this has a property ***[cookieless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** which can have options as `AutoDetect`,
`UseCookies`, `UseUri`, and `UseDeviceProfile`.

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
<!-- Detailed configuration options --> 
<forms name="MyForm" 
loginUrl="Login.aspx" 
timeout="30" 
cookieless="UseCookies"
... />
</authentication>
```

So, in your case the value for cookieless seems to be either : `UseUri` OR `AutoDetect`, although `UseDeviceProfile` is possible too.

**UseUri**:If this configuration option is selected, cookies will not be used for
authentication. Instead, the runtime encodes the forms authentication ticket
into the request URL

**AutoDetect**:Results in the use of cookies if the client browser supports cookies. Otherwise, URL encoding of the ticket will be used.

**UseDeviceProfile** :: Results in the use of cookies or URL encoding based on a device profile configuration stored on the web server. These profiles are stored in .browser files in the c:[WinDir]\Microsoft.NET\Framework[Version]\CONFIG\Browsers directory.

Since you don't want to use cookieless, set the value for `cookieless` to `UseCookies`.

**NOTE**: When using the setting `cookieless="UseCookies"` , requires the client browser to support cookies. If the browser does not support
cookies, forms authentication will simply not work. As
it will never receive a valid authentication cookie from the browser, ASP.NET
redirects back to the login page over and over again, and you end up in an
endless loop of presented login pages

Comment: OK, great I didn't know about the setting in authentication/forms. It seems to default to UseDeviceProfile. I will try to set this to UseCookies. It is strange though that this only happens sometimes for a given user. Normally it works just fine.

Comment: You can also check the setting specified for UseDeviceProfile by checking  .browser files in the c:[WinDir]\Microsoft.NET\Framework[Version]\CONFIG\Browsers directory. Updated my answer for this setting

Comment: I have already checked the device profiles in the Browser folder, but I don't see any obvious cause there. It is just the standard files without any changes. I have done the changes in production now, but it will take a day or two until I can confirm that setting forms/cookieless to UseCookies fixes the problem. This only happens every other day or so...

Comment: I had a similar situation, for what it is worth [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31431776/1257607) is what I did to solve it.