# Unable to create asp.net session on a cookieless web application

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, redirect, cookieless

I have a **cookieless** web application based on asp.net 4.5.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="10"/>
```

I access this application from a redirection, by sending the session Id in the request:

> GET /WebApp/(S(stbb3233i55s0quqxs40x))/default.aspx HTTP/1.1

for some reason unknown I can't create the asp.net session and got stucked in a redirect loop. Any thoughts about how to overcome this situation?.

Comment: Do you have any redirection rules in IIS that it could be tripping over, that don't have a wildcard allowing the cookieless session ID?

Comment: Could you explain how the redirection is done?

Comment: The redirection is done through a reverse proxy server, there are no specific rules in this server, just the redirection in the INI file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AdrianWragg, I found it! 
The redirection was done through a reverse proxy but this server had an ISAPI filter that was removing the session Id from the request, after I removed the ISAPI filter everything worked just fine.

[image: Wrong ISAPI filter]

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to change your configuration in the **web.config** to:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="10"/>
```

?

Comment: Technically that would work, but I imagine there's a reason why the OP is using a cookieless application which they haven't stated.

Comment: @AdrianWragg is right, this suggestion makes it work but then I don't have a cookieless application

Comment: @DanielV I was trying to understand if the problem was related to something else, rather to the redirection.

Comment: @Juanito Requests for clarification should be in comments, not answers.